# Packaging of MATLAB code

Tags: oop, matlab, class, packaging

In the recent question "[How to organize MATLAB code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326609/how-to-organize-matlab-code)" Andrew Janke mentioned in his answer using classes to organize MATLAB functions into packages:

> ... consider rewriting some of the code as objects, using stateless utility
>   classes with class methods and private functions as ways of packaging related
>   functions together and providing some encapsulation. ... In
>   classic MATLAB, **classes are your only way of doing some sort of packages**.

Would you please provide more information on it? Links, code examples to understand the concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loren hosted a guest blogger to discuss this issue:

http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2008/08/18/when-to-create-classes-in-matlab/

I made a simple video about this:

http://blogs.mathworks.com/videos/2008/07/07/advanced-matlab-class-system-for-oop-in-matlab-introduction/

Of course the MATLAB documentation for this:

http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_oop/brh2rgw.html

Answer (score 2):

**Don't use classes for packaging**

Classes in Matlab has known limitaitons (starting with [performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1693429/is-matlab-oop-slow-or-am-i-doing-something-wrong) scalability, etc). 
Before going into using OOP in MATLAB, first learn ["+" packaging](http://www.mathworks.ch/ch/help/matlab/matlab_oop/scoping-classes-with-packages.html) (i.e. not "@" or handles).

Statements like `import foo.bar` work just as expected (also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13459284/packaging-or-modular-programming-in-matlab-analog-of-pythons-import)).

*A word of caution:* if you really need OOP, just consider picking another language before doing it in MATLAB. I had to rewrite my OOP MATLAB code back to functions and packages because OOP implementation by Mathworks is just "immature". First troubles start with `parfor` where stuff has to be serialized with an overhead and then still breaks way too often.