# Is it possible to differentiate between a class method and a function with a class parameter in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, class, function, methods

Say I have a class Foo with a method bar.

I also have an independent function bar which takes objects of class Foo.

Is it possible to differentiate the two? Or are they the same?

```
foo = Foo()
foo.bar() %Is this call equivalent
bar(foo)  %to this call?
```

Edit: Example of my infinite loop problem:

Project class

```
classdef Project
...
function predict(proj)
    ...
    run_predict;
end
```

run_predict (called after "proj = Project()" )

```
...
predict(proj);
```

predict function (this is never called!)

```
function predict(proj);
...
end
```

Comment: Why would they be equivalent? They are entirely unrelated.

Comment: How about to try it and find out?

Comment: I did, and I got stuck in an infinite loop because the class method was always getting called, while the independent function would never get called. I'm wondering how to keep the same function names, but differentiate the function calls, since they're in two separate contexts.

Comment: Aha, then it would be great if you could edit your question and produce the minimal example which produces the described behavio (infinite loop). How about that?

Comment: Added an example! It's fairly minimal, but covers the basics.

Comment: They both will call the class method. This is dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17576506/how-to-force-matlab-to-call-a-regular-function-rather-than-class-method-when-the

Answer (score 0):

If you type `which -all bar`, you should see something like:

```
C:\path\to\function\bar.m
C:\path\to\class\Foo.m     % Foo method
```

Methods are identified with the `% Classname method` comment.

Or perhaps you were asking something more complex about method/function dispatch?

Comment: That's exactly what I see, however, I can't seem to call the function – it always calls the class method, even if I use the `bar(foo)` syntax.

Comment: That's right - class methods always take precedence over functions on the path. I believe that both subfunctions and private functions take precedence over class methods: So in your example, if you make your function `predict` a subfunction of `run_predict` (you'll have to make `run_predict` a function rather than a script to do that) it should get called in preference to the class method. Alternatively make it a private function by creating a directory private in the same directory as `run_predict`, and put the `predict` function there.

Comment: ...cont. Note that both the above suggestions will restrict how the `predict` function can be called. If it's a subfunction of `run_predict`, only `run_predict` can call it. If it's a private function, only code within the directory containing the private directory can call it.