# Matlab: set current working directory as top priority in path

Tags: matlab, path

In one of my projects, I have a Matlab function called eom.m. When I try to call it, I get errors. I have realised this is because Matlab calls a simulink file, eom.slx, instead, which is in one of the toolboxes.

I would prefer not to rename the function, so I was wondering how I could change the order in the Matlab path so that the folder I call Matlab from always has top priority. That is to say how I can ensure that the files in my current working directory are always those that are called in fact.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Which MATLAB version are you using?

Comment: Have to checked out [this](https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/function-precedence-order.html) link on function precedence?

Comment: Make a subfolder named `private` in you current directory and add your function in it which is what suggested in the above mentioned link (point5). Also duplicated here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17578095/5698672

Comment: 2017a. Thanks. The answer below is also working well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it programmatically using [`addpath`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/addpath.html) with the `'-begin'` option.

1. You can use *command syntax*:

   ```
   addpath c:/path/you/want -begin
   ```

   Enclose with quotes if the path contains spaces:

   ```
   addpath 'c:/path /you/ want' -begin
   ```
2. Alternatively, you can use *function syntax*:

   ```
   addpath('c:/path/you/want', '-begin')
   ```

   This allows having the path stored in a variable:

   ```
   p = 'c:/path/you/want';
   addpath(p, '-begin')
   ```