# packages (folders begin with “+”) in matlab programming

Tags: matlab, package

When I addpath a folder in MATLAB2013a, the packages (folders begin with “+”) that are in the folder are not accessible. What is the solution?
My main problem is when I want to add a Breakpoints in an m file that is in a package.

Answer (score 2):

Matlab implements namespaces with folders beginning with a plus sign: [stackoverflow:namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748302/what-is-the-closest-thing-matlab-has-to-namespaces)

You can simply add the parent folder to your Matlab path and call the function `+foo/bar.m` in this fashion:

```
x = foo.bar(123);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, But my problem is when I want to add a Breakpoints in an m file that is in a package.

Comment: @keyvanrad you should specify that in your question then.

Comment: @keyvanrad: You can add the breakpoint anywhere in your main script or in any subfunction. The breakpoint disappears, when your program contains `clear all`. For further details refer to [matlab help](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html#brqxeeu-182)